# Is this sentence clear in terms of meaning? Does it need any modifications?

Tags: meaning

> A translator should have a good command of both languages so that texts rendered from or to Arabic would have the native air and of course make sense to the target audience.

Regarding the sentence meaning that refers to "two" languages being translated to and from, should I make the word "audience" plural?

And is the sentence clear in terms of meaning? What could be the best native-like sentences that give the same message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this sentence is clear. You should not make audience plural